# Convert FitNesse XML Test Result to JUnit format

Tags: xml, powershell, junit, fitnesse

We are currently using FitNesse for our automation testing. I am in the process of integrating this into our builds using VSTS and need to publish the test results.

FitNesse Test results get saved in xml and need to be converted to a JUnit format that VSTS can understand. Ideally i would like to use a powershell script that will make the transform to JUnit possible.

Has anyone done this before or have an example script to convert to JUnit format.

Many Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? is XSLT an option?

Comment: I have an XSLT file that I'm unfortunately unable to share... The tricky part is opening the results for each individual test in the test suite, inside `FitNesseRoot/files/testResults` (use the XSLT `document` function), and then extracting the level of detail you want to see.

Comment: thanks  @legoscia, this sounds like it could be a good option. Are you using the XSLT function to convert to JUnit? I aim keen to get this into a powershell script. Is this something you have done? Or have an example that could help me get started please?

Comment: No idea how you'd do this in powershell. I have an XSLT stylesheet, and use the `xsltproc` tool to convert the Fitnesse XML output file into Junit xml. Just found this, which was probably what I started with: https://gist.github.com/sergebug/a11e57b267caf89c1187
It tells you which tests failed, but doesn't give you details of the failures.

Comment: Seems like that XSLT code should be credited to Andy Palmer: http://andypalmer.com/2009/04/showing-fitnesse-test-results-in-hudson/

Comment: Fitnesse also comes with a junit runner which can be incorporated into a maven or ant job which will produce output in junit output (and html) wouldn't that be easier to use?

Comment: thanks @FriedHoeben, that would be a lot easier to use. However we do not want to use maven or ant job. As we use vsts as our build automation tool and are using .Net

Comment: Just for future reference: VSTS can build maven projects no problem: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/build/maven

Answer (score 0):

Maybe misunderstanding something here but:
http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.AdministeringFitNesse.RestfulServices

**Responders**

```
format=junit    Produces simple jUnit XML format
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys. We created our own powershell script in the end to take the classnames, suites and failure types. Posted below if anyone would like to use.

```html
param([string]$outpath, [string]$testserver, [string]$suitename)

$uri = "http://" + $testserver + "/" + $suitename + "?suite&format=xml"
$resultString = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri
$xml = New-Object xml
$xml.LoadXml($resultString)

$tests = @{}

foreach($result in $xml.testResults.result)
{
    $pageName = $result.pageHistoryLink.Substring(0, $result.pageHistoryLink.IndexOf("?"))
    foreach ($ir in $result.instructions.instructionResult)
    {
        $i =$ir.instruction.Replace("=",":")
        $argsloc = $i.LastIndexOf(', args:')
        if ($argsloc -gt 0)
        {
            $i=$i.Substring(0, $argsloc) + "}"
        }

        $instr =convertFrom-Json $i
        if ($instr.instruction -eq "import")
        {
            continue

        }

        if ($instr.instruction -eq "make")
        {
            $t=New-Object psobject
            $classname = $pagename + "." + $instr.className
            Add-Member -InputObject $t -MemberType NoteProperty -Name className -Value $classname
            Add-Member -InputObject $t -MemberType NoteProperty -Name scenarios -Value @{}
            $tests.add($pagename + "." + $instr.instanceName, $t)    
        }

        if ($instr.instruction -eq "call")
        {
      
          $t=$tests[$pagename + "." + $instr.instanceName]
          if (-not($t.scenarios.ContainsKey($ir.expectation.row)))
          {
            $s=New-Object psobject
            Add-Member -InputObject $s -MemberType NoteProperty -Name pass -Value $true
            Add-Member -InputObject $s -MemberType NoteProperty -Name failures -Value @()
            $t.scenarios.add($ir.expectation.row, $s)    
          }

          if ($ir.expectation.status -eq $null)
          {
            continue
          }

          if ($ir.expectation.status -eq "pass")
          {
            continue
          }

          $LASTEXITCODE = 1
          $scenario = $t.scenarios[$ir.expectation.row]
          $scenario.pass =$false
          $scenario.failures += ("Method Name: "+ $instr.methodName + " - Expected: " + $ir.expectation.expected + ", Actual: " + $ir.expectation.actual)  

        }
    }
}

$doc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument  
    
$suites = $doc.CreateElement("testsuites")
$res=$doc.AppendChild($suites)

$ts = $doc.CreateElement("testsuite")
$res=$suites.AppendChild($ts)

foreach ($testkey in $tests.Keys)
{
    $test = $tests[$testkey]
    $test
    foreach ($scenariokey in $test.scenarios.Keys)
    {
        $scenario =$test.scenarios[$scenariokey]
        $tc = $doc.CreateElement("testcase")

        $attr=$doc.CreateAttribute("classname")
        $res=$attr.Value= $test.className
        $res=$tc.Attributes.Append($attr)
        
        $attr=$doc.CreateAttribute("name")
        $res=$attr.Value= $test.className
        $res=$tc.Attributes.Append($attr)

        if (-not($scenario.pass)) 
        {
            $errString = [string]::Join(": ", $scenario.failures)
            $scenario.failures.GetType()
            $fail = $doc.CreateElement("failure")
            $attr=$doc.CreateAttribute("message")
            $res=$attr.Value= $errString
            $res=$fail.Attributes.Append($attr)
            #$fail.innertext = $errString
            $res=$tc.AppendChild($fail)
        }

        $res=$ts.AppendChild($tc)
    }
}

$doc.Save($outpath)
```